# Can we create artemis diverts using command line?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want to configure some diverts in broker.xml. Is there a way by which I can achieve it using command line during broker creation itself?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Artemis "create" command doesn't support diverts.  In fact, none of the Artemis CLI commands support creating diverts.